# javascript to remember user choice for country & city then they should redirect to a page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, redirect

I need a JavaScript code snippet to remember user choice (stored with cookies). Once a user selects country and city, they should be redirected to a specific page, depending on the previous choice.

Also they can change anytime country and city.

Comment: Good luck with that, you already know that you'll need cookies, so better start coding !

Comment: You should accept *your question* as accepted. Start coding.

Comment: Clarified the question

Comment: i dont know any code. i just have little knowledge about this. please provide me the code. thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));  //set d to x days (e.g. 30 days (= 2592000 seconds))
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();         //set to valid date
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;  //set cookie
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); //put all the cookies in the document into an array, called 'ca'
    for (var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {    //for each cookie
        var c = ca[i];                   //set 'c' to that cookie
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);  //get rid of superfluous characters
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)  //if 'c' == 'cname' (e.g. the cookie you're checking for
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);  //return the value of that cookie
    }
    return "";
}

function onSelect(country, city) {
   //call this function when the user has selected their country and city
    setCookie("country", country, 30);
}

if (getCookie("country") && getCookie("city")) {
    //this function will run automatically at first,
    //if the user has already selected country and city (i.e. those cookies already exist)
        //redirect to specific page
}
```

*This is adapted from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp*

Comment: please provide me the full code including html as i am a beginner . thank u